# Scrollable table in flex layout

Tags: html-table, flexbox

I'm trying to create an HTML layout with header, footer and 3 content sections. It does work for simple sections; however for the code below, I get table2 spanning past footer:

```
<html>
  <body style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
<header style="text-align: center">
  Header
</header>
<section style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex: 1">
  <section>
    <table style="border-style: dotted">
      <thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table id="table2" style="border-style: dotted">
      <thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td><td>Val3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section style="border-style: dotted">test</section>
  <section style="border-style: solid">another</section>
</section>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to make table2 scrollable, ideally only `tbody` part?

Comment: Set min-height less than the actual height and overflow: scroll;

Comment: What is the best way to set height so table2 occupies all available space?